# How do you approach this? Statistics and probability question

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

**On average, the number of traffic accidents in a city is 1 per day. What is the average number of days one needs to wait until the third time that no accident occurs in a day?**

Not sure how to proceed with this question, I feel it has something to do with exponential distribution, but I'm not sure how to use it to derive the average/expected value cause it seems like I'm lacking some information.

Edit:
The options are MCQ, and the answer was 3e.

I have no idea how it was derived. I have tried finding the probability of 0 accidents happening in a day using poison distribution. Since they want period of days to wait for the event of having 3 days of no accident, I would assume exponential would also be involved, but I don't know how to link those up to get the average.

Another edit: This isn't a homework question, just a question from a quiz, results are out and I'm confused on how this answer is derived. The lecturer did not give any working.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that the first thing you have to do is to model the problem...that is, declare which distribution you assume the random variable follows.  This is critical.  After all, if the distribution is constant (exactly one accident each day) then the answer is undefined.

Comment: You are right that information is missing. Suppose that it is known that each Monday exactly 7 accidents occur and on the other days none. E.g. no one is allowed to enter traffic in this city at all, except 7 people on Monday that are then obliged by law to crash into each other. This extra information is consistent with the problem as stated and makes it relatively easy to solve the problem. If you can come up with a different way of adding extra information making it possible to solve the problem, but leading to a different solution then you have proven that indeed information was lacking.

Comment: However, if this was e.g. a homework assignment, showing that information is lacking is probably not the goal of the exercise. Instead you should carefully look at the source of the problem and see if the information isn't hiding somewhere.

Comment: The problem wants you to assume the number of accidents on any given day has a $\text{Poisson}(1)$ distribution. Assuming this, the probability that no accidents occur on a given day is $\frac{1}{e}$. If $X$ is the number of days that pass until you observe your third accident$-$free day, then $$\mathbb{P}(X=x)={x-1 \choose 2}(1/e)^3(1-1/e)^{x-3}:x=3,4,5,...$$ Then $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{x=3}^{\infty}x\mathbb{P}(X=x)=3e$$ This, of course, assumes the number of accidents from day to day are independent and follows a Poisson distribution.

Comment: You could also get this result by recognizing that $X$ is the sum of three iid $\text{Geometric}(1/e)$ distributions.

Comment: @MatthewH. Thanks so much! I got it!